# ISO C++ forbids declaration of "something" with no type

Tags: c++, templates

I am new to template programming in C++, so I decided to start with writing a template list. I get this error on line `Node<T> *head;` and `Node<T> *tail;`

Here is my header file (because errors appear only there):

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

using namespace std;

template <class T> class List {

public:
    List();
    T get(const int n);
    void add(const T element);
private:
    Node<T> *head;
    Node<T> *tail;
    int size;
};

template <class T> class Node {
public :
    Node();
    T get();
    void setNext(const Node<T> *next);
    Node<T> getNext();
    void setValue(const T value);
private:
   T value;
   Node *next;
};

#endif // LIST_H
```

Oh, and I tried adding `typename` before `Node<T>`, but it gave me `expected nested-name-specifier before 'Node'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your `Node` definition in front of `List` or forward declare `Node`

```
template <class T> class Node;  // forward declaration for Node

template <class T> class List {    
public:
    List();
    T get(const int n); 
    void add(const T element);
....
};


template <class T> class Node {
public :
....
};

 ....
```

Answer (score 2):

It just means you have to put the `Node` class template definition before that of `List`, or forward declare `Node` before `List`. The `List` class template needs to know of the existence of a `Node` class template.

As an aside, remove the `using namespace std`, [it is bad in general, and very bad in headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

template <class T> class Node { /* as before */ };

template <class T> class List { /* as before };

#endif // LIST_H
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a forward declaration of the `Node` class template before the `List` because during the `List` declaration, the compiler doesn't know the `Node` class:

```
template <class T> class Node;  // Forward declaration

template <class T> class List {
    // ...
};

template <class T> class Node{
    // ...
};
```

Or even you can declare your `Node` class before the `List`:

```
template <class T> class Node{
    // ...
};

template <class T> class List {
    // ...
};
```

By the way, `using namespace std;` in [header is considered a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).